# Search text highlight using regex even the text has commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble finding a regular expression based solution to a problem involving searching for values in a HTML table.

In the screenshot further down below, the column named "Amount" may contain "," between the digits. It's our client's requirement that when they search for "247" (using the search field) values like "2,47..." *or* those like "247" in the column, should be highlighted.

I tried to solve it using regular expressions but it did not work as expected:

```
const regex = new RegExp(
  searchTerm
  ?.toString()
  .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
  .replace(/\s+/g, "|") + ",?",
  "gi"
);
```

[image: Screenshot of the HTML document]

How do I highlight "2,47" in the preceding example?

```js
const regex = new RegExp(
  247
  ?.toString()
  .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
  .replace(/\s+/g, "|") + ",?",
  "gi"
);

console.log('247','247'.match(regex))
console.log('2,47','2,47'.match(regex))
console.log('2.47','2.47'.match(regex))
```

Comment: Please clarify, why should it be highlighted: you allow single `,` in between of result, or any number of them, or any number of punctuation?

Comment: Can your input allow entering `,` to start with? You seem to have typed "247" in your example while asking about "24,7". The comma in your code seems to be used to separate search items, can you confirm?

Comment: Why do you invent your own language on top of regular expression syntax -- translating search term to a regular expression using a series of convolutions like that? A search term is typically letters, numbers and whitespace, sometimes quotes, and definitely including a comma (`,`). That is interpreted as-is by most regular expression parsers, certainly including that of `RegExp`. For everything else it will be parsed as expected -- if the user wants to find `2,47` a regular expression `2,47` will _match_ the string `2,47`. Don't complicate things -- that's what got you into trouble.

Comment: As per the above example, the column containing Amount will have "," between the numbers. It's our client's requirement that when they search 247 in the search bar the amount containing 2,47 or any value having 247 should be highlighted.

Comment: One approach for such a use case would be to generate all the possible set of strings, (in the above case ["2,47", "24,7", "247"]) and then look for inclusion of these strings in the data to be searched. When i say  inclusion I mean data.forEach(str=>str.includes(item[0])), but this still feels not the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your clarifications, I see no other choice than splitting your string and dynamically inserting an optional `,?` between all your characters. Seems overkill but I don't see any other way to ignore the comas.

FINAL EDIT thanks to markalex:
Much cleaner version, the `,?` are now added only between digits. This way it can be done at the end after escaping the special characters and doesn't need hackish tricks that could affect the robustness.

You also don't need to insert the last `,?`, il will have no effect

```js
const regex = new RegExp(
  247
  ?.toString()
  .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
  .replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/g, ",?")
  .replace(/\s+/g, "|"),
  "gi"
);

console.log('regex: ',
  247
  ?.toString()
  .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
  .replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/g, ",?")
  .replace(/\s+/g, "|")
)

console.log('247','247'.match(regex))
console.log('2,47','2,47'.match(regex))
console.log('2.47','2.47'.match(regex))

const regex2 = new RegExp(
  'question?'
  ?.toString()
  .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
  .replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/g, ",?")
  .replace(/\s+/g, "|"),
  "gi"
);

console.log('regex: ',
  'question?'
  ?.toString()
  .replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&")
  .replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/g, ",?")
  .replace(/\s+/g, "|")
)

console.log('question?','question?'.match(regex2))
console.log('question','question'.match(regex2))
```

Comment: This solution will lead to unexpected behavior if search string contains `?`. `a?b` will be converted to `a,?\,??,?b,?`.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected. Thank you incredibly much @Kaddath.

Comment: @markalex it is not really unexpected behavior, they just won't match. I fixed the regex to include those, it's a bit hackish, there should be a cleaner way. Thanks for noticing anyway!

Comment: @Kaddath, by unexpected I meant that search term `a?b` will not find `a?b` itself.

Comment: @markalex I see, it's a term that have a different meaning (and worse implications) to those that code in C. I think it should be fixed now, but they may be another edge cases

Comment: Yeah, right: my bad. "undesired behavior" would be better I guess) Regarding edge cases: right now ``\\`` will not match ``\,\`` but I doubt that is desired anyway. As for the most clean solution: maybe `.replace(/(?<=\d)(?=\d)/g, ",?")` would better? It will insert `,?` only between to digits.

Comment: @Vimal I have updated my answer thanks to markalex. It is simpler and more robust now

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76034156/16057454), seems to be covering the main usecases, but consider if you have amount that is not only in $ dollars but can be in pounds. That is exactly where the logic can fail.

A different approach can be to store the amount in the format of a number as in 12345 or string "12345" in the DB. This would make it very easy and efficient to make a find/search query on this data.

Now for the purpose of formatting on UI side like a amount $XX,XXX. You can easily use a mask function.

This is reducing the complexity of logic and easily can be modified for furthur client requirements.

Comment: Hello, this probably should have been a comment and not an answer. There is nothing in the question or in my answer that will fail with pounds. There is no indication in the OP's question that the numbers are stored already formatted. This post is about matching digits in the displayed result string. There could be no match if the numbers are formatted with spaces like in french, but the same logic from my answer can be adapted, using `(?:\s|,)?` or something similar instead of `,?`